# How to revert array to orginal form after conditional permute

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

My code:

```
var unpermuted = new byte[]{137, 208, 135, 4, 191, 255, 132, 99, 85, 54, 58, 137, 208, 37, 151, 30};
var longKey = new byte[] {75, 79, 84, 69, 197, 129, 75, 65, 74, 65, 75, 75, 79, 84, 69, 197, 129, 75, 65, 74, 65};

    var permuted = (byte[])unpermuted.Clone();

    for(var i = 0; i < permuted.Length;i++)
    {
        if (i > 1 && (permuted[i] < longKey[i]))
        {
            var swapCont = permuted[i - 1];
            permuted[i - 1] = permuted[i];
            permuted[i] = swapCont;
        }
    }

    printArr(unpermuted);
    Console.WriteLine();
    printArr(permuted);

    // How do I reverse permuted array to unpermuted?
    Console.WriteLine();
    printArr(permuted);
}


public static void printArr(byte[] arr)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.Length;i++)
    {
        Console.Write(arr[i]);
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
}
```

I have unpermute array, make deep copy, and after this, if `keyValue` is higher than value, I swap with previous element.

And the question is:
How to revert permuted array to unpermuted form having **only** LongKey Array and Permuted array?

Comment: `var originalCopy = unpermuted.ToArray();` :)

Comment: Vey funny :)  **having LongKey Array and Permuted array?** :)

Comment: that actually creates a new array with the copy of the elements inside

Comment: This is just one pass of a bubble sort. So all you need to do is run one pass of a bubble sort in reverse (i.e. starting at the end of the array).

Comment: BTW, `for(var i = 0;` followed by `if (i > 1` is the same as `for(var i = 2;` and no `if`.

Comment: @user3386109 I don't think your idea works. Consider the two arrays `[3,1,5,2]` and `[1,3,5,2]`. After the first pass of a bubble sort, both will result in the array `[1,3,2,5]`. There's no information to tell you which of the two arrays you started with, so you can't just reverse the operation.

Comment: @JimMischel I tested my idea on the arrays in the question, and it works. That's not to say that it works in all cases. And maybe you have an example were it doesn't, but your comment is unclear. There are three arrays involved, `key`, `unpermuted`, and `permuted`. It's not clear in your comment which is which.

Comment: @user3386109 The two arrays are unpermuted. Let's assume that they both use the same `longKey` array. I think it's possible to end up in an ambiguous situation.

Comment: @user3386109: Yes, I see that I need to come up with a counter example. And, no, those aren't the results. Either OP's code has a bug, or he intentionally doesn't want the first element in the array (at index 0) to change.

Comment: @JimMischel Ok, you're right, the permutation is reversible only when a very specific condition is met. And oddly enough, the example in the question meets that requirement in the three places where it matters.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to "unpermute" the array, given the information that you have.

Imagine that you have the following:

```
longkey = [1,2,3,9,5]
array   = [3,4,9,5,6]
```

Running your code, the result will be `[3,4,5,9,6]`.

But if the original array is `[3,4,5,9,6]`, the result is the same.

As you can see, there are multiple permutations of the original array that give the same output. And there's not enough information in the result and the `longkey` array to tell you what the original array was.

In general, if you have a 3-item sequence anywhere in which the following is true, then it's not possible to reliably reverse the operation.

```
longkey = [b, c, d]
array   = [x, y, z]
```

Where:

```
b <= x, b <= y
c <  x, c > y
d <= z
```

For example:

```
longkey = [...,3,9,5,...]
array   = [...,9,5,6,...]
```

The key here is that the 9 can never swap with the thing to its left, and the 6 will never swap with the 5. So the 5 and 9 cannot move except to swap places with each other. If the original order is `[9,5,6]`, the final order will be `[5,9,6]`. And if the original order is `[5,9,6]`, the result is, again, `[5,9,6]`.